# Is there a functional difference between using a tuple in an in clause vs using a concatenation of two columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

To give an overly simplified example, assume I have a table 'places' containing the columns 'country' and 'city' both of which contain strings.

| COUNTRY | CITY |
| --- | --- |
| France | Paris |
| France | Marseille |
| USA | New York |

Oracle permits searching for a row containing a particular country-city pair using either of the following forms

A: `select * from places where ('France','Paris') in (select country, city from places)`

or

B: `select * from places where 'FranceParis' in (select country || city from places)`

I most often encounter A when troubleshooting poor performance in queries that use concatenation of two columns from one table to search another. For example assume we have another table called 'disney'.

| DIS_COUNTRY | DIS_CITY |
| --- | --- |
| France | Paris |
| USA | Orlando |

one *could* do the following;

A: `select * from places where country||'|'||city in (select dis_country||'|'||dis_city from disney)`

but I struggle to see any advantage to this approach over using;

B: `select * from places where (country, city) in (select dis_country, dis_city from disney)`

Other than computational cost, is there a functional difference between these two approaches that could lead to different output or are they effectively equivalent?

I've run several tests of both methods and on the test data I've used they return the same results.

Comment: I'd assume execution wise, separate columns will use index - i.e. go much faster.

Comment: Also, in worst case concatenation will give invalid results. E.g. `'AbCd' || 'Ef` = `'Ab' || 'CdEf'`.

Comment: Many thanks @jarlh in the test cases I've run form A is indeed a lot faster while returning precicely the same output as form B. I'd also prefer to use form A to avoid the concatenation resulting in invalid matches. Given my inexperience with oracle I'm just a little concerned I may be overlooking a fundamental difference between the two methods.

Comment: Obviously the first performs best. But your question is about functional equivalence. As @jarlh points out, the concatenation doesn't specify where the break is between the terms. If you wanted it to be equivalent and the datatypes are strings, you can add a delimiter `where 'France|Paris' in (select country||'|'||city from places)`. But what about other datatypes? Short answer then is don't use the concatenation method. It not only disables all kinds of optimizer options and makes it hard to estimate cardinality, but also gets tricky to code with a longer list or with other datatypes.

Comment: Thank you @PaulW, whenever I encounter someone using the concatenation method it's almost always in the context of troubleshooting a slow query presumably for exactly the reasons you've given. I guess in asking this I'm just looking for a sanity check that I'm not overlooking not an obvious scenario where the concatenation would be the better approach.

Comment: It would be almost never the better approach. I say "almost" because there are some rare situations where something like this becomes necessary. For example, I built a SQL-generating service in PL/SQL that crawls a strictly modelled application data model and builds SQL so my front-end and middleware don't have to be table-structure aware, but I only allowed for one child key-to-parent, so in the rare case where I need multiple key cols, a virtual col concatenating 2 other cols was easier than augmenting the system to handle multiple keys. But even here it isn't the "best", but a quick hack.

Answer (score 2):

Handling NULLs is an important functional difference between using an IN CLAUSE versus using concatenation. For example, let's include the island nation Nauru in the PLACES table. According to some sources, the country has no cities, so let's use a NULL in the CITY column:

```
SQL> create table places as
  2  select 'France' country, 'Paris'      city from dual union all
  3  select 'France' country, 'Marseilles' city from dual union all
  4  select 'USA'    country, 'New York'   city from dual union all
  5  select 'Nauru'  country, null         city from dual;

Table created.
```

A direct comparison between NULLs will not return a match:

```
SQL> select * from places where ('Nauru',null) in (select country, city from places);

no rows selected
```

But a comparison between concatenated strings *will* return a match:

```
SQL> select * from places where 'Nauru'||null in (select country || city from places);

COUNTR CITY
------ ----------
France Paris
France Marseilles
USA    New York
Nauru
```

Concatenation can avoid more complicated NULL comparisons. The code doesn't feel very clean, but this is the kind of trick you'll often see in a data warehouse where most of the data is dirty anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Apart the NULL problem, the first form, that SQL call "Row Value Constructor" is perfect for BTree Indexing, rather than the concatenate form taht cannot use such index, except if you create a functionnal index...

But functionnal indexes are poorly used unlike indexes that have plain columns...